# Using ssh to remotely execute command Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm new to python and I cannot solve the reason my code is not working . 
I'm trying to connect to several servers by hostname list on a file via ssh(using paramiko).

Something weird happens,the code is working only if there is one hostname in the file, if it has more than that, it is not working . 
just to be clear the loop is working fine.

hope you can assist me, thanks in advance !

The code:

> ```
> import sys
> import os
> import paramiko
>
> client=paramiko.SSHClient()
> client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>
> username='yadayada'
> password='ladida'
> ipFile=open("C:\Users\garmiza\Documents\Scripts\TrapToHpsimLinuxIPList.txt","r")
>
>
> for line in iter(ipFile):
>    print "sending trap from " + line
>    client.connect(line,username=username,password=password)
>    command="snmptrap -v 1 -c public 16.19.203.96 enterprises.232 {clientIP} 6 11003 0".format(clientIP=line)
>    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
>
>
> ipFile.close()
> ```

The errors:

```
  File "C:/Users/zaza/PycharmProjects/linuxTrapSending/linuxTrapSending.py", line 16, in <module>

    client.connect(line,username=username,password=password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 301, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 199, in _families_and_addresses
    hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Inside your loop, print `line` to make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: Yeah , i did , printing the ip addresses fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx

> The getaddrinfo function provides protocol-independent translation from an ANSI host name to an address.

And the error code 11001:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx#WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND

> Host not found.
>   No such host is known. The name is not an official host name or alias, or it cannot be found in the database(s) being queried. This error may also be returned for protocol and service queries, and means that the specified name could not be found in the relevant database.

You must be passing a wrong hostname (or just a host which doesn't exist).

Comment: thanks, I have replaced the ip address with hosts name, and something weird happens.
If i have one line(one hostname) in the file it's working , if i have more than one it's showing the exact same error. 
What could it be ?
(just to be clear i have checked the loop and it's printing the lines just fine)

Comment: Not sure. Maybe the way you pass the address. Or maybe paramiko doesn't accept an IPv4 as address.

Comment: yeah... i have changed from ip to hostname

Answer (score 0):

OK , I solved it. The problem is that the values in a list are readed as : hostname\n that what caused the error and the reason it worked with one hostname in a file.